# Read a 2-D array in a parallel way using C

Tags: c, io, openmp, fread, fseek

I am working on a physical simulation code (C program) with intensive I/O. At each time step, I need to load a 2-D array from a binary file on the disk followed by processing it. To load the array, I use fseek to move the pointer and fread to actually read the data. However, this I/O process significantly slows down the program, especially when dealing with large models.

So I am thinking about using OpenMP to speed up. Basically, I read the binary file row by row using fseek.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(ix, Fp)
    for (ix = 0; ix < nx; ix++) {
        fseek(Fp, sizeof(float) * (nx * nz * (it - 2) + ix * nz), SEEK_SET);  // Move the pointer
        fread(array[ix], sizeof(float), nz, Fp);  // Read array
    }
```

The code works fine without the #pragma line but it gives me a segmentation fault when I include this line. So any idea how to fix it? Or more generally, what is the fastest way to read a 2-D (even multidimensional) arrays from a binary file (probably parallel)? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Parallelizing IO is unlikely to improve the performance. You have a single piece of HW there. I would think you are going even make it worse, as you make the head to jump back and forth instead of reading sequentially (in case of classical magnetic HDD. SSDs might have their own quirks).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using mmap() or mmap64() to make the whole file an array in memory.  No buffered FILE*, no fseek(), just a pointer and careful pointer arithmetic.  You can overwrite data, too, if you configure that and if that helps.  This uses all RAM as a cache of the file, and VM to read/write it, even if your code aborts.  Other processes can also look at the file with no overhead, using mmap() or any kind of file I/O!  It's one of the most powerful library routines!  Of course, if the data is written in string form or the wrong endian order, there is extra overhead.  There are also mmap() options to copy on write!